# Java: method takes a string and constructs a program that puts out the same string using a for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

This is an experiment. My friend is trying to get a grasp on java and writes text outputs like the following example. I wanted to test myself if I could provide a program that could generate them.

For a String, the program should count each character and save how often and at what index it occurred and then generate a for-clause with an if-clause for each character like the following:

I want to put in e.g. "1234123412341234"
and get something like

```
public class ClauseText {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 12) {
            System.out.print("a");
        }
        if (i == 1 || i == 5 || i == 9 || i == 13) {
            System.out.print("b");
        }
        if (i == 2 || i == 6 || i == 10 || i == 14) {
            System.out.print("c");
        }
        if (i == 3 || i == 7 || i == 11 || i == 15) {
            System.out.print("d");
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I've come up with is so far is the following. I convert the input String to a char array and iterate through the array. I maintain three array lists, one for the character, one for how often it occurred, and one saves an ArrayList of Integers containing the index position where the character occurred.

To make it simpler, I decided to make all ArrayLists the size 128 and put each character to the index equalling its respective ASCII value.

But it doesn't seem to work, it's a simple Indexoutofboundsexception, however, I don't know what is wrong. Here:

The output only goes this far and then it crashes:

```
public class ClauseText {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 3) {
            System.out.print("a");
        }
        if (i == 1 || i == 4) {
            System.out.print("b");
        }
        if (i == 2 || i == 5
```

The program is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringToProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define and create program
    String className = "ClauseText";
    String program = makeProgram("abcabc", className);
}

public static String makeProgram(String myWord, String className) {
    String program = "public class " + className + " {\n";
    program += "    public static void main(String[] args) {\n";
    program += "        for(int i = 0; i < " + myWord.length()
            + "; i++) {\n";
    char[] myWordChar = myWord.toCharArray();

    // For each character, we have to save the index where it occurs and how
    // often. We want to hash it into the ArrayLists by ASCII value.
    ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> indices = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> amounts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Initialize three lists with the size of the ASCII table
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        characters.add(null);
        indices.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        amounts.add(0);
    }

    // Now we iterate through each occurrence. We use the ASCII code to hash
    // and find specific letters.
    for (int i = 0; i < myWordChar.length; i++) {

        int index = (int) myWordChar[i]; // the hash value of the char

        if (amounts.get(index).equals(0)) {
            // create new entries and append them to the
            // given index of the lists
            characters.add(index, myWordChar[i]);
            indices.add(index, new ArrayList<Integer>());
            indices.get(index).add((Integer) i);
            amounts.add(index, 1);
        } else {
            // there is already an entry. modify it.
            amounts.add(index, amounts.get(index) + 1); // ++
            indices.get(index).add((Integer) i);
        }
    }

    // Now, we iterate through the occurrences list. First, we check for
    // each index if an object is saved there.
    for (int i = 0; i < amounts.size(); i++) {
        if (amounts.get(i) > 0) {
            // When this is the case, we append an if clause.
            program += "            if (i == ";
            for (int j = 0; j < amounts.get(i); j++) {
                // The amount of options in the if clause depends on how
                // often the character occurred in the string.
                program += indices.get(i).get(j);
                if (j + 1 < amounts.get(i)) {
                    // we still have to append an option
                    program += " || i == ";
                }
            }
            program += ") {\n";
            program += "                System.out.print(\""
                    + characters.get(i) + "\");\n";
            program += "            }\n";
        }
    }
    program += "        }\n";
    program += "    }\n";
    program += "}";

    System.out.println(program);
    return program;
}

}
```

The error is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at StringToProgram.makeProgram(StringToProgram.java:60)
at StringToProgram.main(StringToProgram.java:8)
```

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: This is kind of Lisp macro. Java is not the best choice for sort of operations. Could you write more about what problem you try to solve?

Comment: @Vash-DamianLeszczyński: "What problem you try to solve..." almost certainly homework.

Comment: which line is line 60 in your code?

Comment: Added the error message. This is for a friend who is new to Java. I want her to guess the output of the programs.

Comment: I remember trying to teach my wife Java when we first met...

Comment: Line 60: in the third for-loop, in its nested for-loop:     program += indices.get(i).get(j);

Comment: Input "abcabc" as written in main(). I think the error is in the second for-loop when trying to add to the Arraylist indices. It doesn't seem to work very well adding ArrayLists of Integers to an ArrayList.

Comment: @user3788181, If you try to learn someone Java, use examples that you comprehend. IF you create so complex that you can not implement it. How you will explain to 3rd person.

Comment: I don't want to use this to explain something, I want to use its output.

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception because in some cases list returned in this line does not contain elements.

You need following code:

```
List<Integer> numbers = indices.get(i);
for (Integer number : numbers) {
    program += number;
    program += " || i == ";
}
```

instead your code:

```
program += indices.get(i).get(j);
if (j + 1 < amounts.get(i)) {
   // we still have to append an option
   program += " || i == ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost there … the output is

Comment: Tried it. Works most of the time, but sometimes it doesn't enter the loop when it should.

Comment: It enters in the loop always when the list has elements. In your code you are trying to take element from empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should start simpler:

```
public class StringToProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // define and create program
        String className = "ClauseText";
        String program = makeProgram("a\nbca\rbc", className);
    }

    public static String makeProgram(String myWord, String className) {
        myWord = myWord.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\t", "\\t");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\b", "\\b");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\n", "\\n");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\r", "\\r");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\f", "\\f");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\'", "\\\'");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\"", "\\\"");
        myWord = myWord.replace("\t", "\\t");
        String program = "public class " + className + " {";
        program += "    public static void main(String[] args) {";
        program += "        System.out.println(\"" + myWord + "\");";
        program += "    }";
        program += "}";
        System.out.println(program);
        return program;
    }

}
```

I didn't use org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils for clarity.